# Turning data to wide-form

Tags: r, dplyr, wide-format-data

I have data in this format:

| ID | risk | severity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | green |
| 1 | A | amber |
| 1 | A | amber |
| 1 | B | amber |
| 1 | B | amber |
| 1 | B | amber |
| 2 | B | green |
| 2 | B | green |
| 2 | B | amber |
| 2 | C | green |
| 2 | C | red |
| 2 | C | red |

I want to convert it to this format using dplyr on R-Studio:

| ID | A | min_sev | max_sev | B | min_sev | max_sev | C | min_sev | max_sev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | green | amber | 3 | amber | amber | 0 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 0 | NA | NA | 3 | green | amber | C | green | red |

where,

*min_sev = minimum severity*

*max_sev = maximum severity*

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand how colours are minimum/maximum. It would be more helpful if you provide your data with `dput(head(mydf))`

Comment: What is your preferred ordering of {red, green, amber}? Green is lowest, red is highest?

Comment: I think it's first and last.

Comment: fyi, R doesn't really like frames with duplicate column names, and `tibble` is a bit more aggressive and discouraging it.

Comment: @GregorThomas Yes, green is the lowest severity, amber medium, and red highest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch @r2evans, here is an even simpler solution with nest and unnest:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, risk) %>%
  summarise(min_sev = first(severity),
            max_sev = last(severity),
            count = n()) %>%
  group_by(ID, risk) %>%
  nest() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = risk, values_from = data) %>%
  unnest(cols = everything(), names_sep = "_")
```

Comment: Fails: `x Column \`severity\` doesn't exist.`

Comment: I believe I fixed it.

Comment: @dcsuka to be clear, the parameter ''values_from'' should be df right? If I understand correctly, it's the same as the original data frame. Also, I am getting an error when using the data.table.

Comment: data is the column automatically created by nest(), the code runs exactly as written if the df is in tibble form. You could convert back to data.table afterwards.